# How to give right to a user to add opportunity team member

Tags: opportunity, opportunity-teams

I need to give right to an user to "Add" Opportunity Team member on a opportunity but the uses doesn't come higher in the role hierarchy than the owner.

Is there any workaround through which user can see "Add" button on opportunity Team member without having higher role than opportunity Owner?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 7):

Opportunity Team Members cannot be created unless you are the owner of the Opportunity or are above the role hierarchy.

However, there are two ways you can achieve this:

1) Create a Visual force page and then have the logic to add/delete Team Members

2) Create a custom object and write a trigger on the custom object to add team members. Since triggers run on system context, it will create the team member.

Hope it helped.

Answer (score 1):

We have implemented a custom VisualForce page in the past that allows multiple users to add team members, therefore overriding the security need of having 1) Edit access and 2) Owner or above owner in hierarchy.

Answer (score 0):

We took the Flow approach.  Set up a Screen Flow component on Opp Record and set to run as system to bypass sharing, ownership and role hierarchy.